# vba code for algorithm to assign track file gps UTM coordinates (East Africa) to an overlay 5x5km grid cell

Tags: raster, geocoding, vector-grid, vba

The GPS coordinates are temporarily imported in to an **Access database** from **DNR Garmin files** (downloaded as dbf file(s)), and then exported for mapping in **AEJEE** (ArcExplorer Education Edition).

I need to be able to run the vba code on importing the dbf aerial track files and populate another database table with the **grid cell reference associated with the track file coordinates**, so that I get **grid cell 'hits' per flight** -          ie. the number of times each 5x5km grid cell has been 'visited' by the aircraft.

Any help with this would be fantastic!

Comment: do you have access to ArcGIS or just ArcExplorer?

Comment: If you can convert the coords to UTM you could just round the X and Y to the nearest 5000, and then group on those fields.